# Can't access local resource with NSURL. Strange

Tags: xcode, nsbundle

My iOS app wants to play a local audio file. So, in xCode, I’ve added a file "audio.m4a" to my project. It resides on the top level of the file tree, but

```
    NSURL *audioFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
URLForResource:@"audio" 
withExtension:@"m4a"];
```

returns `nil`. There must be a stupid oversight. **What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *myFile = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"audio" ofType: @"m4a"];
NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myFile];
```

and check whether that file present in `Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources"`

Comment: "…and check whether that file is present in Build Phases…" did the trick. I knew it was something stupid. Today I learned: If you add an image to your project, it gets automagically copied into your app.bundle. If you add a sound file, not so.

Comment: This code is wrong. There is no difference in file behaviour between `-pathForResource:…` and `-URLForResource:…`. And more importantly, `+URLWithString:` is completely the wrong method for creating URLs from file paths

Answer (score 1):

## Swift

*Since neither answer is complete, and the solution is disseminated in the comments, let me offer a **Swift** alternative. and a step-by-step response.*

The original **Objective-C** code is correct:

```
NSURL *audioFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    URLForResource:@"audio" 
    withExtension:@"m4a"];
```

**Swift**

```
let audioFileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
    "audio",
    withExtension: "m4a")
```

**Target Membership**

This was probably an oversight when *originally* adding the resource to the project. You must select adequate targets when adding these files:

[image: Add to targets]

Regardless of the language, ensure that your file is *Project > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources*. You need not to do that by hand. Instead, use the **File Inspector**. Select your resource (on the left panel) and verify it's target membership (on the right panel):

[image: Target Membership]

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Use this code to play an audio file */
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player play];
```